# Missing articles?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, determiners

Aren't some articles missing in the following sentence?

> ... when traditional pattern of landscape became established.

Or is it something else that is wrong with this sentence?

[Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hedge&oldid=395519337#History).

Comment: There isn't anything wrong... Where would you put the articles?

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: the sentence does not read well. Perhaps "when the traditional pattern of the landscape became established."

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: or perhaps "when traditional patterns of the landscape became established.".

Comment: I think I would have written "when traditional patterns of landscape became established".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a missing article, or more likely a missing plural.

Answer (score 5):

When you write "the traditional patterns", you're referring to specific patterns. There was no article in that case because the author meant traditional patterns in general. But I think I would have written "**traditional patterns**" (plural) instead of "traditional pattern".

Compare the following:

> I like cats.

(I like cats in general.)

> I like the cats that I have at home.